# HTTPD listening in IPv6, according netstat, but reacheable in IPv4

Tags: ipv6, httpd, ipv4, netstat

Using Openstack, I have a Web GUI (horizon) hosted on my server (HTTPS).

When I do a `netstat -lt | grep https`, I have:

```
tcp6       0      0 [::]:https              [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

With `lsof -i :443`, I have:

```
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
httpd    5250   root    6u  IPv6  27390      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
httpd   17675 apache    6u  IPv6  27390      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
httpd   17676 apache    6u  IPv6  27390      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
httpd   17677 apache    6u  IPv6  27390      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
httpd   17678 apache    6u  IPv6  27390      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
httpd   17679 apache    6u  IPv6  27390      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
httpd   17680 apache    6u  IPv6  27390      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
httpd   17681 apache    6u  IPv6  27390      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
httpd   17682 apache    6u  IPv6  27390      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
httpd   27444 apache    6u  IPv6  27390      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
```

However the server is reachable in IPv4. It's ok for me but I wonder why there is not an entry with netstat like this:

```
tcp       0      0 0.0.0.0:https              0.0.0.0:*                  LISTEN
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I believe that on Linux, binding to [::] (IPv6) results in receiving both IPv6 and IPv4 traffic (by default).  I believe these are referred to as **IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses**.  `netstat` simply shows the IPv6 entry only, because there's technically only a single bind, that happens to support both IPv4 and IPv6.

There's a bit of information on the [Apache site](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/bind.html#ipv6).

It's possible for software to not use IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses and bind to both 0.0.0.0 and [::] separately and hence show up twice in `netstat`, but it's a design choice on the part of the developers.

Comment: It's not: tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
     tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN

Comment: It's not what?  Your example appears to indicate an ssh daemon which is listening on both an IPv4 port and an IPv6 port, rather than a single combined IPv4-mapped IPv6 address.  I'm not sure what your point is.

Comment: That down vote is inappropriate. This is the correct answer. Software can bind to the wildcard address on IPv6 and accept both IPv4 and IPv6 connections on it. On Linux this is even the default. The SSH software in your example chose not to.

Comment: @drookie What relevance is that?